# passing ruby arrays to javascript code (jquery) in a haml view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying Highcharts graph on a haml template using jQuery/javascript.  Here is a snippet showing the standalone graph from the demo code in HighCharts site:

```
:javascript

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'volume_chart'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
      },
      xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
        pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
      },
      series: [{            
        data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
        pointStart: 1
      }]
    });
  });
```

This works fine.  Now I am trying to set the series data from a ruby/rails array in the show.html.haml file like so:

```
...
- data_array        = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
...
:javascript

  $(document).ready(function() {
  ...
      series: [{            
        data: "#{data_array}",
        pointStart: 1
      }]
    });
  });
```

This gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `to_js' for [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]:Array
```

How can I pass data_array from my ruby/rails code to the javascript/jquery code?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Bharat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'json'

...

"#{data_array.to_json}"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I independently found the following:  1.  Do not name this array "data" something as this will interfere with jQuery's remote data transfer mechanism.  2.  Having renamed this array as "test_array"  I could say what you have above, i.e. "#{test_array.to_json" or "#{test_array.inspect}" or just "#{test_array}", all of which work.  I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in HAML there is no need to use `to_json`

```
   :javascript
     $(document).ready(function() {
       ...
       series: [{            
         data: #{ruby_array},
         pointStart: 1
       }]
     });
    });
```

will perfectly work